# Removing href based on specific innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I want to disable specific links based on the innterHTML, but retain the anchor tag for style reasons. Here is what I've come up with, but i'm hoping for something cleaner. I have quite a few links to disable. Please share if you can think of a more elegant solution. Thanks!

```js
$('a').filter(function() {
  return this.innerHTML == "Freducation® and Recruitment";
}).replaceWith('<a>Freducation® and Recruitment</a>');
$('a').filter(function() {
  return this.innerHTML == "Stationery";
}).replaceWith('<a>Stationery</a>');
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=69" class="categorySidebarLabelLevel1 categorySidebarLabel" title="">In-Store Signage</a>
<a href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=94" class="categorySidebarLabelLevel1 categorySidebarLabel" title="">Freducation® and Recruitment</a>
<a href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=96" class="categorySidebarLabelLevel1 categorySidebarLabel" title="">Outdoor Signage</a>
<a href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=153" class="categorySidebarLabelLevel1 categorySidebarLabel" title="Stationery, Letterhead, Business cards">Stationery</a>
```

Comment: well, you'd be looping on your `a` tags twice. could just `$.each()` on the entire 'a' tag set and do your search/replace within there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery's `replaceWith()` like this

```
$('a').replaceWith(function() {
    return ["Freducation® and Recruitment", "Stationery"].indexOf($(this).text()) != -1 ?
           $('<a />', {text : $(this).text()}) : false;
});
```

or just disable the anchors

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return ["Freducation® and Recruitment", "Stationery"].indexOf($(this).text()) != -1;
}).on('click', function() {
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than completely replacing the link, you could simply replace the `href` attribute with `javascript: void(0);`, which will kill the click action in browsers as far back as IE6 (at least).

And you can use the jQuery `:contains()` filter to find the links that you want.

This should do it:

```
$("a:contains('Freducation® and Recruitment')").attr("href", "javascript: void(0);");
$("a:contains('Stationery')").attr("href", "javascript: void(0);");
```

If you wanted to make it more dynamic, you could even pass in an array of strings to match and loop through them:

```
var aLinksToDisable = ["Freducation® and Recruitment", "Stationery", "Something Else"];

for (i = 0; i < aLinksToDisable.length; i++) {
    $("a:contains('" + aLinksToDisable[i] + "')").attr("href", "javascript: void(0);");
}
```

You could even set that up as a function with a parameter, if that would be easier for your situation.

**EDIT:**

For the record, that would convert your links into:

```
<a href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=69" class="categorySidebarLabelLevel1 categorySidebarLabel" title="">In-Store Signage</a>
<a href="javascript: void(0);" class="categorySidebarLabelLevel1 categorySidebarLabel" title="">Freducation® and Recruitment</a>
<a href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=96" class="categorySidebarLabelLevel1 categorySidebarLabel" title="">Outdoor Signage</a>
<a href="javascript: void(0);" class="categorySidebarLabelLevel1 categorySidebarLabel" title="Stationery, Letterhead, Business cards">Stationery</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply remove the `href` attribute:

```js
$('a').filter(function() {
  return (this.innerHTML == "Freducation® and Recruitment") ||
         (this.innerHTML == "Stationery");
}).
removeAttr('href');
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=69" class="categorySidebarLabelLevel1 categorySidebarLabel" title="">In-Store Signage</a>
<a href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=94" class="categorySidebarLabelLevel1 categorySidebarLabel" title="">Freducation® and Recruitment</a>
<a href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=96" class="categorySidebarLabelLevel1 categorySidebarLabel" title="">Outdoor Signage</a>
<a href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=153" class="categorySidebarLabelLevel1 categorySidebarLabel" title="Stationery, Letterhead, Business cards">Stationery</a>
```